# Unit testing private constructors and getter setters

Tags: java, junit, assertions

I have a class `Address`, a class `AddressTest` and I am trying to write unit tests for its constructors and getter setters.

### Address:

```
/**
 * The bean Address.
 *
 * @author Sandeep Chatterjee
 * @since 24/8/2015
 */
class Address {

    private BigInteger addressId;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private String contactNo;

    private String postalCode;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Address() {
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param name       Addressee Name
     * @param address    Full Postal Address
     * @param contactNo  Addressee Contact Number
     * @param postalCode Addressee postal code
     */
    private Address(String name, String address, String contactNo, String postalCode) {
        this.addressId = new BigInteger(256, new Random());
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    /**
     * Static factory
     *
     * @param name       Addressee Name
     * @param address    Full Postal Address
     * @param contactNo  Addressee Contact Number
     * @param postalCode Addressee postal code
     * @return An Address instance
     */
    public static Address createAddress(String name, String address, String contactNo, String postalCode) {
        return new Address(name, address, contactNo, postalCode);
    }

    /* Object overrides */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                .append("address", address)
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(addressId);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Address) {
            Address that = (Address) object;
            return Objects.equal(this.addressId, that.addressId);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Accessors and Mutators */

    /**
     * @return Get Address Id
     */
    public BigInteger getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    /**
     * @param addressId Set Address Id
     */
    public void setAddressId(BigInteger addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Get Addressee Name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name Set Addressee Name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return Get Full Postal Address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * @param address Set Full Postal Address
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /**
     * @return Get Addressee Contact Number
     */
    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    /**
     * @param contactNo Set Addressee Contact Number
     */
    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    /**
     * @return Get Addressee postal code
     */
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param postalCode Set Addressee postal code
     */
    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }
}
```

### AddressTest:

```
/**
 * All tests for class Address
 *
 * @author Sandeep Chatterjee
 * @since 24/8/2015
 */
public class AddressTest {

    /**
     * @see [http://www.jqno.nl/equalsverifier/]
     * @see [https://github.com/jqno/equalsverifier/blob/master/README.md]
     */
    @Test
    public void equalsContract() {
        EqualsVerifier.forClass(Address.class)
                .suppress(Warning.NONFINAL_FIELDS, Warning.NULL_FIELDS)
                .verify();
    }


    @Test
    public void testPrivateConstructor() {
        final Constructor<?>[] constructors = Address.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors) {
            Assert.assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetterSetterPostalCode() {
        final String postalCode = "456098";
        final Address address = new Address();
        address.setPostalCode("456098");
        Assert.assertEquals(address.getPostalCode(), postalCode);
    }
}
```

Am I doing this correctly or is there a better way? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Address() {
}
```

You have just defeated your purpose of making a `private` constructor... and not only that, it makes it possible to create an `Address` instance with `null` fields. Even if this should be possible in your codebase (as used in `testGetterSetterPostalCode()`), then I will suggest simply sticking to two `public` constructors - one with the arguments, and one without. The `public static createAddress()` then becomes unnecessary.

I am also unsure about the viability of `testPrivateConstructor()`... unit testing should be asserting *the behavior of your class's features*, not the visibility of its constructors and methods.

Comment: Thanks h.j.k. Actually, I was going through Joshua Bloch's Effective Java where in Chapter 2 he mentions "A class can provide its clients with static factory methods instead of, or ***in addition to***, constructors." So, I thought may be it won't harm to provide both. When you say that `unit testing should be asserting the behavior of your class's features, not the visibility of its constructors and methods`, do you mean or suggest that it is not a good idea to unit test getter setters and constructors?

Comment: There are many threads on SO suugesting that one should write test cases for constructors and getter-setters. :)

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee even for those kinds of test cases, they probably contain non-trivial logic that applies some kind of input validation - and that will be what the unit testing is for. Unit testing is not about asserting your `private` constructor remains `private` when your unit test is running - if that ever becomes `false`, you'll have other problems to worry about.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee "it won't harm to provide both": yeah, but at the same time [you aren't gonna need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI)... ;)

Answer (score 8):

As a more general remark I like to add two excerpts from a book I recently read named "The Art of Unit Testing" by Roy Osherove. It helped me a lot and it is really worth reading – and it also valuable for your question.

### Testing Private or Protected Methods

> Private or protected methods are usually private for a good reason in
> the developer’s mind. Sometimes it’s to hide implementation details,
> so that the implementation can change later without the end
> functionality changing. It could also be for security-related or
> IP-related reasons (obfuscation, for example).
>
> When you test a private
> method, you’re testing against a contract internal to the system,
> which may well change. Internal contracts are dynamic, and they can
> change when you refactor the system. When they change, your test could
> fail because some internal work is being done differently, even though
> the overall functionality of the system remains the same. For testing
> purposes, the public contract (the overall functionality) is all that
> you need to care about. Testing the functionality of private methods
> may lead to breaking tests, even though the overall functionality is
> correct. (Section 7.2.1, p.182)

### Testing Getters and Setters

Osherove writes that a "unit test is an automated piece of code that invokes the method or class being tested and then checks some assumptions about the **logical behavior of that method or class**". Logical code is code that has

- an IF statement
- a loop
- switch or case statements
- calculations or
- any other type of decision-making code.

And hence he concludes:

> Properties (getters/setters in Java) are good examples of code that
> usually doesn’t contain any logic, and so doesn’t require testing. But
> watch out: once you add any check inside the property, you’ll want to
> make sure that logic is being tested. (Section 1.4, p. 12)